# Inclusion of uppersemicontinuous maps in continuous maps

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, semicontinuous-functions

I have a question please. Is there a result about the inclusion of uppersemicontinuous maps in continuous maps ? I mean if F is uppersemicontinuous, is there always a map G continuous such that $F\subset G$.

Thank you in advance for your answers,

Comment: Could you clarify the meaning of "uppersemicontinuous" and "continuous" here? It seems like you are referring to set-valued maps, and I believe these terms are not universal in this context.

Comment: Yes! Here are the definitions: $F:dom(F)\subset R^n\rightrightarrows R^n$  is uppersemicontinuous at $x\in dom(F)$ if $\forall \epsilon>0$, there exists a neighborhood of $x$, let's denote it $U(x)$, such that $\forall y\in U(x)\cap dom(F)$, $F(y)\subset F(x)+\epsilon \mathbb{B}$ where $\mathbb{B}$ denotes the unit closed ball, The map $F$ is lower semicontinuous at $x\in dom(F)$ if $\forall \epsilon >0$ and $y\in F(x)$, there exists $U(x)$ such that $\forall z\in U(x)\cap dom(F)$, $\exists t\in F(z)$ such that $|t-y|\leq \epsilon$. Continuous if it is both upper and lower semicontinious.

Comment: Ah, good to know. For the record, I would call these "metric-usc" and "metric-lsc" respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $F : \Bbb{R} \rightrightarrows \Bbb{R}$, defined by
$$F(x) = \begin{cases} \{1\} & \text{if } x > 0 \\ \{-1\} & \text{if }x < 0 \\ \{-1, 1\} & \text{if } x = 0. \end{cases}$$
Then $F$ is USC with full domain. Locally around $x_0 < 0$ and $x_0 > 1$, the function is single-valued and constant, making it continuous. At $x_0 = 0$, $F(0) + [-\varepsilon, \varepsilon]$ will always contain both $\{1\}$ and $\{-1\}$, and hence $F(x)$ for any $x \in \Bbb{R}$, making $F$ USC at $0$.

Now, suppose $G \subseteq F$, also with full domain. We have exactly $3$ options: $G(x) = F(x)$ for $x \neq 0$ and either:

- $G(0) = \{-1\}$,
- $G(0) = \{1\}$, or
- $G(0) = \{-1, 1\} = F(0)$.

It's not difficult to see that the first two options are not USC. If we add $[0.5, 0.5]$ to $G(0)$, then in the first case, $G(x) \not\subseteq G(0) + [0.5, 0.5]$ for any $x > 0$. Similarly, in the second case, this is true for $x < 0$. Either way, this is a failure of USC.

In the third case, $G = F$, which is not LSC. If we choose $y = 1 \in F(0)$, and $\varepsilon = 1$, then any $x < 0$ the only possible $t \in F(x)$ is $t = -1$, which is not within $\varepsilon$ of $1$.

So, no, it's not always possible to choose a continuous function from a USC function.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. This property is thus generally not true. I will try to search eventually for conditions on set-valued maps under which this could be true. Have a good day!